# Heroku - how to pull data from one database and put it to another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, backup

We have 2 Heroku apps - the first one is production and the second one is staging. I would like to pull data from one table from the production app (it's table **users** with all user's data) and push it to the staging database.

After a little research I found the addon called **pgbackups** - I have just a few concerns:
Does this addon also allow to get data only from one table, not from the whole database?

The second thing is this - let's say that on production are users with IDs from **1** to **300**. On the staging version users with IDs from **1** to **10**. How to put those 300 users from the production to the staging version the way, that these 300 users would be counted from the ID **11** (we would like to keep our staging users in the staging database as well).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*There are ways to do this in straight SQL. If you're comfortable with that, go for it. This way is for devs comfortable in Rails -- so we pull data out using JSON, and create users with a new ID in the new database from that JSON.*

---

Since you're pulling only 1 table, AND you want to reset the IDs to the new database, I recommend:

1. bring a copy of the database locally with pbackups
2. `File.open('yourfile.json', 'wb') {|file| file << User.all.to_json }`
3. Connect to your new database, and move yourfile.json up there

then:

```
users_json = JSON.parse(File.read('yourfile.json'))
users_json.each do |json|
  json.delete("id")
  User.create(json)
end
```

Comment: I have never did something like this before, so I would like to ask you regarding to passwords and tokens - will all password hashes and tokens saved correctly, so the users will be able to log in with their credentials?

Comment: And one more thing - how to pull data in JSON format? The date are coded and saved as "dump".

Comment: 1) That depends on the authentication system. You'll likely need to try and see. 2) If you follow my instructions, it's in json format.

Comment: Well, but if I open the downloaded file, I see inside only hexa data, nothing like JSON structure.

Comment: You must be referring to step 1, bring a copy of the of the postgres locally? You should read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 1):

This script pulls data from your Heroku database into a local postgres database. You need the `pgbackups` addon installed. Execute it from the root directory of your Heroku app.

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
# This script asks Heroku to backup the current production data, then downloads that dump and imports it into the local db.
# It is at least 3 times quicker than heroku db:pull, and we can only do it because we are dumping from postgres to postgres.
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
curl -o tmp/latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -d your_db_name tmp/latest.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476272/469697). You can use a library called [forceps](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/forceps) to do exactly what you are asking for.